# Как сделать ограничение на выполнение команды раз в N минут?

Tags: c#, .net, discord, .net-core, discord-api

Я разрабатываю **экономического бота**, и нужно сделать ограничение на заработок валюты раз в N минут. На Python я делал это с помощью JSON файла. Записывал **последний успешный вызов команды, и вычитанием делал проверку**. Но есть ли **более простой способ сделать тоже самое на C#**, **без JSON'а?** Команды создаю с помощью модулей `ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>`.

Для разработки использую NuGet пакет "Discord.Net".

Comment: Любые методы в любых языках программирования будут основываться на том, что у вас где-то хранится дата последнего вызова и периодически сравнивается с интервалом. Где хранить эту дату -- ваш выбор: хотите в файле, хотите в базе данных, хотите просто в оперативной памяти (статическое поле класса).

Comment: Json - это просто данные. Можно ли писать и читать json в дотнете? - [можно](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0). Периодические задачи вообще куча вариантов сделать. Есть таймеры, есть сон, есть асинхронное ожидание по времени.

Comment: Самый простой и быстрый(с точки зрения разработки) вариант - это json. Если данных очень много (json уже на десятки мегабайт), то нужна бд (SQLite очень простой вариант), если мало и нужно самостоятельно смотерть/править - Xml тоже хороший вариант, но с ним гемор случается.